# What is the source of Gita Jayanti date?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita

Gita Jayanti is the birthday of Bhagavad Gita, the sacred text of Hindus. It's celebrated on the Shukla Ekadashi, 11th day of waxing moon of Margashirsha month of the Hindu calendar.

Where is the source from which we come to know that this is the day Krishna sang the Gita?

Comment: "the sacred text of Hindus." No A sacred text!

Comment: @Wikash_ You are always welcome to make an edit.

Comment: Are you asking why it is celebrated on Ekadashi when the war started on Amavaysa? The date of the war being in the waxing moon of Margashirsha month of the Hindu calendar is really well established. Or are you asking how the date of the war was established?

Comment: @VARUN.N RAO Sorry to bother you. Suppose I provide proof that the war was fought in the waxing moon of Margashirsha month of the Hindu calendar then isn't it logical that Gita was recited during the war and thus Gita Jayanthi should be celebrated in this month?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer this question based on Dating of Mahabharat.

Shukla Ekadashi of Gita Jayanti is accepted in Puranas.

However Mahabharata does not give the Tithi/Nakshatra of Gita Jayanti. It simply says that the last war day (18) must be a Shravana nakshatra day and it must be an Amavasya or very close to it(K14 leading into Amavasya). Hence first war day must be Rohini/Mrigasira

And the Tithi of first war day must be Shukla Paksha 13/14

Hence first war day according to legend is either Shukla Paksha 13 according to calculation and backed up by Kane and others (source is Anumana from Mahabharata text) or Shukla paksha 11 according to tradition. In any case the war cannot start on an Amavasya as per what is said by Nilesh Oak (some others also claim this and is completely wrong)

Verse from Udyoga Parva 140:18 quoted as evidence foe starting war on Amavasya actually simply mentions that war preparedness is to be commenced at that time and in any case 7 days is too short a time for Mahabharata war to happen (according to the verse war preparations are to be started in 7 days from Karna Krishna Samvada)

[image]

Source : Here is [the paper](https://www.academia.edu/43238545/Debunking_the_1432BCE_war_proposal_for_the_Mahabharata) by [Manish Pandit](https://birmingham.academia.edu/ManishPandit) showing 6 major points of failure of 1432BCE including major timelines, eclipses, Saturn and Mars.

Chapter 11 of MM Pandit's book clearly shows the Moon in Rohini at Midday. "*Sharadante Himagame*" issue is faced by all 3KBCE dates.

[image]

Comment: You comment on your own post?

Comment: earlier comments are deleted bro!

Comment: Where exactly does it say that war ended on Shravana?

Comment: This answer is not supported by any citations. It's supported by Puranas. Which puranas, where??